# Display a path using markers

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to display the path followed by my differential drive base using rviz.
I tried doing the same by using a sphere type marker.
However, it changed the position with time.

Is there any way I can display the entire path using the coordinates from a tf frame with markers?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66274/display-a-path-using-markers/) by [Ratan Sadan](https://answers.ros.org/users/3482/ratan-sadan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-06-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You just need to give a different ns for each marker. I guess you use the following code to specify a marker:

```
visualization_msgs::Marker marker;
marker.type = visualization_msgs::Marker::SPHERE;
marker.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
...
marker.ns = "markerName"
```

You need to change the "markerName", e.g. "marker0","marker1","marker2"...

---

Originally posted by [yangyangcv](https://answers.ros.org/users/3011/yangyangcv/) with karma: 741 on 2013-06-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-07-01**:
It's probably better to change the id instead of the namespace. There are also specific path displays in rviz.